# WKWebView retains itself

Tags: swift, wkwebview

Compare the following tests:

```
func testWebView_dealloc() {
    var obj: WKWebView? = WKWebView()
    weak var objUnderTest = obj

    obj = nil

    XCTAssertNil(obj) // true
    XCTAssertNil(objUnderTest) // false
}

func testCustomObject_dealloc() {
    class MyClass {}

    var obj: MyClass? = MyClass()
    weak var objUnderTest = obj

    obj = nil

    XCTAssertNil(obj) // true
    XCTAssertNil(objUnderTest) // true
}
```

The `WKWebView` doesn't appear to deallocate at all, whereas the custom class deallocates just fine.

Am I missing something here or is this a bug with the `WKWebView`?

It gets even weirder if simplified like this:

```
weak var obj = WKWebView() // Instance will be immediately deallocated because variable 'obj' is 'weak'

print(obj) // Optional(<WKWebView: 0x7facee832200; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000fb6ee0>>)
```

Immediately deallocated you say? I Guess not.

Comment: Are you running these tests in a playground?

Comment: @Chris nope, regular iOS Unit Test project executed in the simulator.

Comment: What Xcode version & iOS SDK version is this?

Comment: The Xcode version (12.5) is irrelevant, it's a UIKit API issue. And iOS 14.